# Google Maps Reverse Geocode Get Lat Long and write to fields

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a postcode held in a field with 'addr_postcode' I need to get the Lat / Long for this post code and write the values to 'adds_c_lat' and 'adds_c_long' what is the best way to achieve this?

I think I need to use the Google API to do this as per this example but I cannot see how to get each value separately and write it into the fields

Example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/07/google-map-geocoding-tutorial-example.html

Thanks

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the example code you gave from the tutorial has this.

```
function geoCode(post) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(post, function(point) {
        if (!point) {
            alert(place + " not found");
        } else {
            $(".my-data-long").val(point.x);
            $(".my-data-lat").val(point.y);
        }
    });
}
function parsePost() {
    var post = $input.val();
    if (post.length === 5) {
        geoCode(post);
    } // end if length === 5.  If length !== 5 (i am assuming postcode = zip code)
}
var $input = $(".my-geo-input");
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
$input.keypress(parsePost);
```

All  i am doing is just using jquery to check to see if the post code meets the requirements on keypress and on change, if there is a valid post code in there, then i simply fire the goeCode method which will fill in the data fields in the html.